# git local repo caching deleted remotes/origin branches

Tags: git, github, repository, branch, git-branch

I have a local repo created with `git clone`

I'm on branch `master`

I perform `git pull` and then `git branch -a`

The list of branches includes `remotes\origin\branch-x` when in fact `branch-x` has been deleted on GitHub.

How can I refresh my local repo branches cache to properly reflect the state on GitHub ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git fetch --prune` to prune the deleted branches. Additionally you can set this as default for a `pull` or `fetch` by running `git config remote.<remote name>.prune true`

Answer (score 1):

```
git remote prune origin <name>
```

> Deletes all stale remote-tracking branches under `<name>`. These stale branches have already been removed from the remote repository referenced by `<name>`, but are still locally available in "remotes/".
>
> With --dry-run option, report what branches will be pruned, but do not actually prune them.

If you don't give any name, it will prune all the branches.